# django unit test for ModelChoiceField form with CheckboxSelectMultiple widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I have a form

```
class TypesForm(forms.Form):
  ....    
  types = forms.ModelChoiceField(
  label='Types',
  queryset=models.Type.objects.all(),
  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
  ...
```

How do I write a unit test for this form, when I want to test multiple boxes selected?

For one field check works following:

```
form = forms.TypesForm({'types': 1})
self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

But anything I tried to set two selected checkboxes, it results in errors:

```
{'types': [u'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}
```

I tried, but these does not work. E.g. :

```
form = forms.TypesForm({'types': [1, 2]})

form = forms.TypesForm({'types': (1, 2)})
```

and other options..

For forms.ModelForm the list [1, 2] works, so there needs to be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ModelChoiceField` allows you to select a *single* object. If you want to allow multiple objects to be selected, use a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField).

In your unit test, pass a list of ids for the field, for example:

```
form = forms.TypesForm({'types': [1, 2]})
```